# Is there any difference between matrices over field with characteristic $0$ and over prime characteristic (particularly over $3$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory, finite-fields

Is there any difference between matrices over the field with characteristic $0$, and over prime characteristic (particularly over $3$), or the All the properties remain over both types of field? As an example "a determinant of skew-symmetric matrix over $R$, of odd order, is zero". Does it always hold for finite field $F_p$ ?  Are diagonalizability conditions the same or not?

Comment: Well, you need to consider over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$ for most diagonalizability rules. But skew symmetric determinants are zero. One big things you lose are positive-definite matrices, since there is no order on $\mathbb F_p.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you can you explain what algebraic closed $\mathbb{F}_p $means?

Comment: (Technically, it depends on how you define skew-symmetric over $\mathbb F_2.$ Is $I$ skew-symmetric over $\mathbb F_2?$ It is if you define the condition as $A+A^T=0.$ )

Comment: okay, Can we any properties of matrices that should hold over finite fields also if we precisely define the definition of that?)

Comment: That’s a big topic, too big for comments. But just as you need to consider complex values when diagonalizing real matrices, you need to expand $\mathbb F_p$ to a field where all polynomials factor into roots. This is called the algebraic closure. The closure still has characteristic $p.$ So if $p=5,$ the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is diagonalizable only in a field that adds a square root of $2$ to $\mathbb F_5.$

Comment: Nonzero vectors can be orthogonal to themselves in positive characteristic.

Comment: In characteristic $0$, scalar matrices (i.e. $a \cdot Id_n$ for a scalar $a$ from the field) have non-zero trace. In characteristic $p$, these have trace $0$ if $p$ divides $n$. This has strong implications e.g. in the theory of Lie algebras, and certainly everywhere else where the trace might be of importance.